# Sort Multidimensional associative array and return the value on same table

Tags: php, associative-array

Below is the code. In this I want to sort based on all 3 keys (i.e. name, quantity and price) values and return the value on the same table creating 2 buttons beside each key in `<tr>` which once clicked will sort the table ASC or DESC as btn indicates. Sry if the question is asked before. Thanks for the help.

```
<?php
$booktable = array('Name' => array('Physics','Maths','Chemistry'),
    'Quantity' => array('3','4','5'),
    'Price' => array('250','350','450')
);
$key = array_keys($booktable);
echo "<table border = '1px'>";
echo"<tr>";

for($x=0;$x<3;$x++) {
    echo"<td>".$key[$x]."</td>";
}

echo"</tr>";

for($x=0;$x<3;$x++) {
    echo"<tr>";

    for($y=0;$y<3;$y++) {
        echo "<td>".$booktable[$key[$y]][$x]."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```